# Why does the inner circle of my fluorescent light sometimes not work?

Tags: light

We have double circular fluorescent lights however the inner light doesn't work sometimes. It has a pull string to operate. It is working today (7th March).

[Panasonic Parc Premier Round Fluoirescent Light (Type 32 + 40 Cool-White) 2 set FCL3240ECWH2KF](http://kakaku.com/lighting/ss_0049_0010/0007/32%8C%60+%8A%DB%8C%5E/search_itemlist.aspx?ssi_kw=32%8C%60+%8A%DB%8C%5E)

Comment: bad ballast, or bad socket.

Comment: Bad ballast, Bad Socket, Loose Wiring.

Answer (score 0):

The cause could be any of the following:

- bad ballast
- bad socket
- loose wiring
- bad pull-switch

Comment: I had six of a batch of Leviton ceramic sockets (made in China) with pull chain switches go bad within a year of going into service. The pull chain switches were faulty. They blinked from first installation, and after some time would require repeated pulls to come on, then would not light at all. I changed to Cooper (also made in China) and these have worked for years with no blinking. After I removed the faulty ones I tested them with an ohmmeter and it was the pull chain switches.

Comment: The fitting worked before- the lights have been replaced not long ago.